# Problem, OpenID Simple Registration Extension

Tags: cakephp, openid

I use OpenID Simple Registration on CakePHP like [this post](http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2008/02/12/using-the-openid-simple-registration-extension/) but this don't work for me.
my code in controller is here:

```
function openid() {
        $returnTo = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$this->webroot.'customers/openid';        
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            try {
                $this->Openid->authenticate($this->data['OpenidUrl']['openid'], $returnTo, 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$this->webroot, array('email'), array('nickname'));
            } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                $this->setMessage($this->data);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->setMessage($e->getMessage());
            }
        } 
        elseif (count($_GET) > 1) {
            $response = $this->Openid->getResponse($returnTo);
            $this->set("test",$_GET);
            if ($response->status == Auth_OpenID_CANCEL) {
                $this->Session->write('OpenIdStatus','Verification cancelled');
            } elseif ($response->status == Auth_OpenID_FAILURE) {
                       $this->Session->write('OpenIdStatus','OpenID verification failed: '.$response->message);
            } elseif ($response->status == Auth_OpenID_SUCCESS) {
                $this->Session->write('OpenIdStatus','successfully authenticated!');
                $sregResponse = Auth_OpenID_SRegResponse::fromSuccessResponse($response);
                        $sregContents = $sregResponse->contents();
                    $this->set("message",$sregContents);
            }
        }
    }
```

What is my wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

The `authenticate` method only expects four params in the current version. The following snippet:

```
$this->Openid->authenticate($this->data['OpenidUrl']['openid'], $returnTo, 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$this->webroot, array('email'), array('nickname'));
```

has to look like:

```
$this->Openid->authenticate($this->data['OpenidUrl']['openid'], $returnTo, 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$this->webroot, array('sreg_required' => array('email'), 'sreg_optional' => array('nickname')));
```

Comment: thanks. i do this but finally $sregContents is empty array! don't return anything. what do i do?

Comment: This could be because the OpenID provider doesn't support SReg. Which OpenID provider(s) do you use for testing?

Comment: No, they don't support SReg, they only support Attribute Exchange. To test whether SReg works in your app, you could use http://myopenid.com

Comment: thanks for "Attribute Exchange". i will try with Attribute Exchange and ask again (: